# When trying to export a project as a JAR the file is instantly viewed as corrupt upon launch

Tags: java, jar, export, executable

I'm having an issue with exportation in Java.  When I launch the JAR file I have created (in Eclipse), it instantly gives me an error, reading:

> "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Deep Dungeons.jar"

My Code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System Objects
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

    // Game variables
    String[] enemies = {"Skeleton" , "Zombie", "Warrior", "Assassin"};
    int maxEnemyHealth = 75;
    int enemyAttackDamage = 25;

    // Player Variables
    int health = 100;
    int attackDamage = 50;
    int numHealthPotions = 5;
    int healthPotionHealAmount = 30;
    int healthPotionDropChance = 50; // Percentage
    int enemiesKilled = 0;
    int maxHealth = 100;

    boolean running = true;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Dungeon!");

    GAME:
        while(running) {
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

            int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth);
            String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];
            System.out.println("\t# " + enemy + " has appeared! #\n");

            while(enemyHealth > 0) {
                System.out.println("\t Your HP: " + health);
                System.out.println("\t " + enemy + "'s HP: " + enemyHealth);
                System.out.println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
                System.out.println("\t1. Attack");
                System.out.println("\t2. Drink health potion");
                System.out.println("\t3. Run!");

                String input = in.nextLine();
                if(input.equals("1")) {
                    int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
                    int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDamage);

                    enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                    health -= damageTaken;

                    System.out.println("\t> You strike the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt +  " damage");
                    System.out.println("\t> You recieve " + damageTaken + " in retaliation!");

                    if (health < 1) {
                        System.out.println("\t You have taken too much damage, you are to weak to go on!");
                        break;
                    }
                } else if(input.equals("2")) {
                    if (numHealthPotions > 0) {
                        health += healthPotionHealAmount;
                        if (health > maxHealth)
                            health = 100;
                        numHealthPotions --;
                        System.out.println("\t> You drink a health potion, healing yourself for " + healthPotionHealAmount + "."
                                         + "\n\t> You now have " + health + " HP."
                                         + "\n\t> You now have " + numHealthPotions + "health potions left.\n");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\t> You have no health potions left! Defeat enemies for a chance to get one!\n");
                    }
                } else if(input.equals("3")) {
                    System.out.println("\tYou run away from the " + enemy + "!");
                    continue GAME;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\nInvalid command!");
                }
            }

            if (health < 1) {
                System.out.println("You limp out of the dungeon, weak from battle.");
                System.out.println("You killed " + enemiesKilled + ".");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(" # " + enemy + " was defeated! # ");
            enemiesKilled ++;
            System.out.println(" # You have " + health + " HP left #");
            if(rand.nextInt(100) > healthPotionDropChance) {
                numHealthPotions ++;
                System.out.println(" # The enemy dropped a health potion! # ");
                System.out.println(" # You have " + numHealthPotions + " health potion(s). # ");

            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("What would you like to do now?");
            System.out.println("1. Continue fighting");
            System.out.println("2. Exit dungeon");

            String input = in.nextLine();

            while(!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid command!");
                input = in.nextLine();
            }

            if (input.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("You continue on your adventure!");
            } else if(input.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("You exit the dungeon, successful from your adventures!");
                System.out.println("You killed " + enemiesKilled + "!");
                break;
            }
        }

    System.out.println("######################");
    System.out.println("# THANKS FOR PLAYING #");
    System.out.println("######################");
}
}
```

Comment: You have provided enough information.  1) Is the JAR file that is corrupted the one that you just exported?  2) How did you export it?  3) Are you using the right pathname for the JAR when you put it on the classpath?

Comment: For what it is worth, your source code is not relevant to the problem.  It is something to do with how you are creating or using the JAR file, or something that is happening to it between the two.

Comment: @stephen-c I figured out the problem, I was exporting the Jar file under the wrong type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  When I was exporting, I should have been attempting to export as a runnable jar file, rather than a regular JAR file.